# An unexpected value returns after execution of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code. Which returns the remainder of number divided by 10 and then appends it to the variable sum. But for some reason I am getting an unexpected value. For e.g if the num is 821 then the remainder should be 1. But the print function returns the value 11. This is very confusing...

```
def sumDigit(num):
    sum = 0
    while(num):
        sum += num % 10
        num = int(num/10)
    print(sum)

num = int(input())
sumDigit(num)
```

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of the function. It is adding up the digits of the number. `8+2+1==11`

Comment: sumDigits is adding up the digits not taking the remainder.

Comment: You seem to have missed the whole *sum* thing going on. You have a function named `sumDigit` and a variable named `sum`, with stuff getting added to it. It's not just a remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. This code sums the modulus of every number entered and exits when you hit return at Enter number.

```
def sumDigit():
    sum = 0
    while True:
        num = input("Enter number:")
        if num == "":
            break
        sum += int(num)%10
        print ("Sum =", sum)

sumDigit()
```